# Confusing symbol in papers on hybrid logic

Tags: logic, notation

In literature about hybrid logic I'm reading for my thesis I've come across the following symbol:

```
::=
```

Now, I've never seen this notation before. I can also not find it explained anywhere (for instance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_symbols)). Mostly I've worked under the assumption it is equal to $:=$, which its usage seems to suggest. Am I correct in assuming that $::= \ \equiv  \ :=$ (talk about a nicely confusing formulation...).

Since the concepts of hybrid logic are not the main focus of the thesis, but its explanation and correctness of fundamental importance I wan't to make sure I'm understanding everything correctly.

Also note that it is NOT a typo, as I've seen it on more than one occasion, in different papers on the subject.

Comment: That may be used to mean "is defined to be". Often you'll see that used in [Backaus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) because '=' is used in the language you are defining.

Comment: I think that BNF form is exactly what is being used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $:=$ and $::=$ have similar meanings. A lot of times that notation is used to mean "equal by definition or by stipulation". So for instance, you might say, "Define the formula $\varphi ::= \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$," or you might say, "Let "$\varphi \vee \psi$" be an abbreviation for "$\neg (\neg\varphi \wedge \neg\psi)$", i.e. let $\varphi \vee \psi ::= \neg(\neg\varphi \wedge \neg\psi)$." You wouldn't say "Therefore, $(x^2 + 1) ::= y^4$", since if there is an equality involved in this case, it's not really equality by stipulation or definition, but rather some *derived* equality. You can basically read it as "is equal to" but it's more emphatic, in that it's equality by definition or stipulation, rather than some derived equality.